# Can't reach information Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a program with 3 options. So the first one is about the employee- (create / remove / update / get information about employee / save to file). Before creating a new employee I have to choose his type(programmer or qa)(difference between them is that programmer have a specific programming language and qa have amount of worked hours). So moving forward when I create a new user I have to enter name / surname / age / prog.language;

The second option in my program is that I can create a team which must be made from 3 employees. So from a list of employees you select one for team lead and other 2 for 'workers'.

And the last one is that you can create a task.
(you need to give a name for task, specific language which is required from a second team member and amount of worked hours from a third member). So this task can be later assigned to a specific team.

So lets talk about my problem right now:
Creating new employees, making new teams works 100%, also creating new tasks works fine as well, but when I try to check does my selected team meets requirements for tasks I'm receiving tons of errors. I've tried to select specific member from a team and check his programming language and receiving null. However, after debugging I saw that information comes,but when i try to reach exactly that language appears null.

[image]

Here's my code how looks my programmer class:

```
package com.wep;
public class Programuotojas extends Darbuotojas {
protected String programavimoKalba;

@Override
public String toString() {
   return "Programuotojas: " + vardas + ",pavarde " + pavarde + ",amzius " + amzius + ",programavimo kalba " + programavimoKalba;
}

public Programuotojas(String vardas, String pavarde, int amzius, String programavimoKalba) {
    super(vardas, pavarde, amzius);
    this.programavimoKalba = programavimoKalba;
}
Programuotojas(){}

public String getProgramavimoKalba() {
    return programavimoKalba;
}

public void setProgramavimoKalba(String programavimoKalba) {
    this.programavimoKalba = programavimoKalba;
}
```

}

And here's my try to check his language:

```
KomanduValdymas.getInstance().komanduArray.get(0).getPirmasDarbuotojas(programuotojas.getProgramavimoKalba());
```

KomanduValdymas is a class where I create new teams. If u need more code from there let me know. Thanks, hope you guys got my problem

```
   private void pridetiDarbuotoja() {
    System.out.println("[1] Pridėti programuotoją");
    System.out.println("[2] Pridėti testuotoją");
    Scanner SI = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userSelects = Integer.parseInt(SI.nextLine());
    if (userSelects == 1) {
        System.out.println("Iveskite:");
        System.out.println("Varda, pavarde, amziu, darbine programavimo kalba");
        String enters[] = SI.nextLine().split(" ");
        darbuotojuArray.add(new Programuotojas(enters[0], enters[1], Integer.parseInt(enters[2]), enters[3]));
        System.out.println("Darbuotojas itrauktas i sarasa");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Iveskite:");
        System.out.println("Varda, pavarde, amziu, isdirbtas testavimo valandas");
        String enters[] = SI.nextLine().split(" ");
        darbuotojuArray.add(new Testuotojas(enters[0], enters[1], Integer.parseInt(enters[2]), Integer.parseInt(enters[3])));
    }
    darbuotojuValdiklis();
}
```

Comment: Either you are not assigning `programuotojas` to anything, or you are assigning it to `null`.

Comment: But without a decent [mcve], it will be anyone's guess

Comment: @JoeC,I do. I updated my code

Comment: I still don't see where you are assigning `programuotojas`.

Comment: Please create a small program of no more than ten lines which shows the same problem.  Otherwise, as @HovercraftFullOfEels said, we'll only be guessing.

Comment: So as I understood i need to assign programuotojas language before I add him to ArrayList?
darbuotojuArray.add(new Programuotojas(enters[0], enters[1], Integer.parseInt(enters[2]),"HERE")), because the last element in my const is his language. @JoeC

Comment: `darbuotojuArray.add(new Programuotojas(...))` does not change the value of `programuotojas` in any way.

Comment: I thought it will give a value for programuotojas without updating.

Comment: _I thought it will give a value for programuotojas without updating._ That is not correct.  See my answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185330/discussion-between-henrikasb-and-joe-c).

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be under the impression that creating a `new Programuotojas` will update the value of your variable `programuotojas` automatically.  That is not the case.

You need a statement that starts with `programuotojas =` in order to affect such a change.

Comment: Struggle is real here right now. Still can't realize this moment right now

Comment: There is no "magic" in Java or programming as the code does what you tell it to, no more and no less.

Comment: But still no [mcve], and so still the question will be of no use to future visitors